# Apache 2.4 Stops Serving Request

Tags: apache

This is something new, Apache is running fine as server on a Windows Server 2012. There is plenty of RAM and CPU and this is the only thing this server does, is an Apache server.

I can restart the service and it will run fine for a little bit then stop serving pages on all sites. I have messed with the worker threads to find a fine line but still having issues.

Currently settings in httpd-mpm.conf file

```
<IfModule mpm_prefork_module>
    StartServers             10
    MinSpareServers          10
    MaxSpareServers         20
    MaxRequestWorkers      250
    MaxConnectionsPerChild   3000
</IfModule>
```

At this point I am not sure what is going on and have tried several suggestions from various websites.

Specs of Server: Windows 2012 R2 VM 2 GB of RAM 1 GB available Running on an SSD storage

This server connects to a MySQL database on the same network as well, there is not latency between the servers.

Comment: is there any lines about any error in log files ?

Comment: That is what is funny, nothing recent has been entered into the logs. I looked for something about max connections and nothing.

Comment: maybe you can try run as console app, that prints more output about situation https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/platform/windows.html